# Git commit checkbox is not ticked

Tags: xcode, git, xcode8

I'm using Xcode 8.0.

Sometimes, when performing a commit, the checkbox is unchecked for some files. Most of the files are ok, though. I've not seen this before. The file is listed when I run `git ls-files` from command line before I tick it. It also have a long `git log` history.

I checked the checkbox and did the commit. I then made a small change, and did the commit again. The file is still unticked. Howcome?

[image]

Have you seen this? Is it a bug, or is my repository or XCode messed up?